# Restore old wallet cache file monero-wallet-gui

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My monero-wallet-gui was synced and the funds were showing. Due to the long duration it took to sync the wallet I reset a new block height in case of a crash. I am unable to find any information regarding the procedure to restore the old wallet cache file.
'The old wallet cache file will be renamed and can be restored later' is the message when new block height is entered.

Answer (score 1):

In your wallet folder, you will find two wallet files, named:

`<wallet-name>`

`<wallet-name>.keys`

The former is the wallet cache (note that the wallet cache file does not have an extension), whereas the latter is the wallet file that contains the keys.

In case the restore height is changed on the `Settings` page -> `Info` tab, the original wallet cache (`<wallet-name>`) will be renamed to `<wallet-name>-old`. Thus, there will be three files:

`<wallet-name>`

`<wallet-name>-old`

`<wallet-name>.keys`

In order to restore the original wallet cache, the GUI needs to 'read' the original file `<wallet-name>-old`. You need to change the name of the new wallet cache to `<wallet-name>-new` and rename `<wallet-name>-old` to `<wallet-name>`. The GUI will subsequently be able to read the original wallet cache and thus the restore will be complete.